# iOS Swift How to remove strings in array from part of string in another array

Tags: arrays, swift

The api call I am making gives me duplicate information in two different elements and I want to remove the duplicate information from the one before displaying the response in my UITableView.
I have looked all over and have played with this for a long time. How do you do the following?:

```
var array1 = ["Hello get", "How rid", "Are of", "You? me"]

let array2 = ["get", "rid", "of", "me"]
```

I have tried amongst many other things:

```
array1 = array1.map { !array2.contains($0) }
```

Looking to get the array:

```
array1 = ["Hello", "How", "Are", "You?"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution using `zip` and `map`.

`zip` puts both arrays together by creating tuples and `map` removes the strings in the second array plus the leading space character from the first with regular expression.

```
let array1 = ["Hello get", "How rid", "Are of", "You? me"]
let array2 = ["get", "rid", "of", "me"]

let result = zip(array1, array2).map{ $0.0.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s" + $0.1, with:"", options:.regularExpression) } 
// ["Hello", "How", "Are", "You?"]
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a little longer but it will cover the case if any word in array2 exists in more than one word in a array1

```
var cleaned = [String]()
array2.forEach( {word in
    let subArray = array1.filter( {$0.contains(word) })
    subArray.forEach( { found in
        var temp = found
        temp.removeSubrange(found.range(of: word)!)
        cleaned.append(temp.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))
    })
})
```